# how do I maintain Aspect Ratio 16/9 on a div and not have it bleed outside the container?

Tags: javascript, css, aspect-ratio

[image]
What I need is

```
x[]x

AND

x
[]
x
```

dynamically maintaining aspect ratio with WIDTH and HEIGHT. Think object-fit but for div.

Example of the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erRvGx?editors=1111

What I have tried without much success

```
.AspectRatio {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.video {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Note the container WIDTH and HEIGHT are fixed here.. it needs to flex to the max size possible and maintain aspect ratio

Comment: Are you ok with non css solution?

Answer (score 0):

**like this ?**

```css
.box1 { width: 200px; height: 100px; position: relative; background-color: red; margin-bottom: 20px; }
.box2 { width: 100px; height: 150px; position: relative; background-color: red; margin-bottom: 20px; }
.box3 { width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative; background-color: red; margin-bottom: 20px; }

.video { width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>

<div class="box2">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>

<div class="box3">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>
```

`top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` this code solves the problem